# How to select an object to be picked up whenever the camera is pointed to that object?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to pick up objects in unity. I have a `gameObject` called `LookObject`. Whenever the camera points to an object, the name of that object will be stored in `LookObject`, then when I press `Space` the object gets picked up. it is working but not completely. The issue I'm facing is that when I look at an object then look at another direction, the `lookObject` still shows the name of the object I was looking at (it doesn't update).
please see this image:
[image]

as shown in the image, the reticle is not pointing to the object. but it is still showing Cube as the Look Object.

Here is `PlayerInteractions` class:

```
 GameObject[] targetObjects;
    List<GameObject> targetObjectsList;
    [Header("InteractableInfo")]
    public float sphereCastRadius = 0.5f;
    public int interactableLayerIndex;
    private Vector3 raycastPos;
    public GameObject lookObject; 
    private PhysicsObjects physicsObject;
    private Camera mainCamera;
    public GameObject winUI;
    private InteractiveObjects interactiveObjects;
    [Header("Pickup")]
    [SerializeField] private Transform pickupParent;
    public GameObject currentlyPickedUpObject;
    private Rigidbody pickupRB;
    [Header("ObjectFollow")]
    [SerializeField] private float minSpeed = 0;
    [SerializeField] private float maxSpeed = 300f;
    [SerializeField] private float maxDistance = 8f;
    private float currentSpeed = 0f;
    private float currentDist = 0f;
    [Header("Rotation")]
    public float rotationSpeed = 100f;
  //  Quaternion lookRot;
    [SerializeField] GameObject TargetsCanvas;
    static bool strikeThrough = false; 
 private void Start()
    {

        mainCamera = Camera.main;
        targetObjects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("TargetObj");
        targetObjectsList = new List<GameObject>();
        foreach (var obj in targetObjects)
        {
            var mytext = CreateText(TargetsCanvas.transform);
            mytext.text = "• Find The " + obj.name;
            Debug.Log(""+ obj.name); 
       }
        
    }

    //A simple visualization of the point we're following in the scene view
    private void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        Gizmos.color = Color.yellow;
        Gizmos.DrawSphere(pickupParent.position, 0.5f);
    }
  void Update()
    {
        //Here we check if we're currently looking at an interactable object
        raycastPos = mainCamera.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Screen.width / 2, Screen.height / 2, 0));
        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.SphereCast(raycastPos, sphereCastRadius, mainCamera.transform.forward, out hit, maxDistance, 1 << interactableLayerIndex))
        {
            lookObject = hit.collider.transform.gameObject;

        }

        //if we press the button of choice
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            //and we're not holding anything
            if (currentlyPickedUpObject == null)
            {
                //and we are looking an interactable object
                if (lookObject != null )
                {
                    PickUpObject();            
                    if (!targetObjectsList.Contains(lookObject.gameObject))
                    {
                        targetObjectsList.Add(lookObject.gameObject);

                        if (targetObjectsList.Count == targetObjects.Length) 
                        {
                          //  Time.timeScale = 0f;
                          //  winUI.SetActive(true);
                            // SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1);
                            // Time.timeScale = 1f;
                        }
                    }
                   
                }
            }
            //if we press the pickup button and have something, we drop it
            else
            {
                BreakConnection();
            }
        }
}
 private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (currentlyPickedUpObject != null)
        {
            currentDist = Vector3.Distance(pickupParent.position, pickupRB.position);
            currentSpeed = Mathf.SmoothStep(minSpeed, maxSpeed, currentDist / maxDistance);
            currentSpeed *= Time.fixedDeltaTime;
            Vector3 direction = pickupParent.position - pickupRB.position;
            pickupRB.velocity = direction.normalized * currentSpeed;
              //Rotation// 
           // lookRot = Quaternion.LookRotation(mainCamera.transform.position - pickupRB.position);
           // lookRot = Quaternion.Slerp(mainCamera.transform.rotation, lookRot, rotationSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
          //  pickupRB.MoveRotation(lookRot);
        }
    }
    //Release the object 
    public void BreakConnection()
    {
        pickupRB.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.None;
        currentlyPickedUpObject = null;
        lookObject = null;
        physicsObject.pickedUp = false;
        currentDist = 0;
    }
    public void PickUpObject()

    {
        physicsObject = lookObject.GetComponentInChildren<PhysicsObjects>();
        currentlyPickedUpObject = lookObject;
        pickupRB = currentlyPickedUpObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        pickupRB.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.FreezeRotation;
        physicsObject.playerInteractions = this;
    }
```

Here is the code attached to objects:

```
 public float waitOnPickup = 0.2f;
    public float breakForce = 35f;
    [HideInInspector] public bool pickedUp = false;
    [HideInInspector] public PlayerInteractions playerInteractions;


    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if (pickedUp)
        {
            if (collision.relativeVelocity.magnitude > breakForce)
            {
                playerInteractions.BreakConnection();
            }

        }
    }

    //this is used to prevent the connection from breaking when you just picked up the object as it sometimes fires a collision with the ground or whatever it is touching
    public IEnumerator PickUp()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(waitOnPickup);
        pickedUp = true;

    }
```

Here is an image of the object inspector:

[image]

how can I make it accurately showing the objects I'm looking at?

Comment: You dont seem to unset the look object when picked up and until something else pickupable is available it’s not going to reset it

Comment: So how would I unset it? and Where exactly should I add this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple fix for this would be to set `lookObject` to null if the SphereCast returns false since that would indicate you are no longer looking at a valid object. Simply adding `else lookObject = null;` to the end of the first if statement in your Update() method should do the trick.